# Give a proof by contradiction to show if the odd integers $1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,$ are placed around a circle...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Give a proof by contradiction to show that if the odd integers $1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,$ are placed randomly around a circle (without repetition), then there must exist three adjacent numbers along the circle whose sum is greater than $32$

How do you approach these problems, I feel lost on how to solve it.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers other than 1 sum to $99$. Splitting the $9$ of them into three consecutive triples, one must sum to at least $33$.

Comment: Nice... Implicit is that the 9 integers 3,5,...,19 form a contiguous path no matter where in the circle the "1" is placed relative to the other numbers [and so as you said either the first third, the middle third, or last third must sum to at least 33, as 3+5+...+19 = 99]. I mention this because it did take me a moment to realize this and so it may be helpful for OP.